# How to access secret (GCP service account json file) during Docker CMD step

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, containers, docker-secrets

I have a Dockerfile like below:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
FROM continuumio/miniconda3
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

# Create directory to store our application
WORKDIR /app

## The following three commands adapted from Dockerfile snippet at
## https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/build_enhancements/#using-ssh-to-access-private-data-in-builds

# Install ssh client and git
RUN apt-get upgrade && apt-get update && apt-get install openssh-client git -y

# Download public key for gitlab.com
RUN mkdir -p -m 0700 ~/.ssh && ssh-keyscan gitlab.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts

# clone my-repo, authenticating using client's ssh-agent. 
RUN --mount=type=ssh git clone git@gitlab.com:mycompany/data-products/my-repo.git /app/

# set up python (conda) environment to run application
RUN conda create --name recenv --file conda-linux-64.lock

# run my-package with the conda environment we just created.
CMD ["conda", "run", "-n", "recenv", "python", "-m", "my_package.train" "path/to/gcp/service/account.json"]
```

This dockerfile builds successfully with `docker build . --no-cache --tag my-package --ssh default` but fails (as expected) on `docker run my-package:latest` with:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: path/to/gcp/service/account.json
```

So I've gotten the ssh secrets management working so the `RUN ...git clone` step uses my ssh/rsa creds successfully. But I'm having trouble using my other secret - my gcp service account json file. The difference is I only need the ssh secret in a `RUN` step but I need my gcp service account secret in my `CMD` step.

While everything I've read, such as [docker docs page on using the --secret flag](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/build_enhancements/#new-docker-build-secret-information), [tutorials](https://pythonspeed.com/articles/docker-build-secrets/) and SO answers I've found, all reference how to pass in a secret to be used in a `RUN` step but not the `CMD` step. But I need to pass my GCP service account json file to my `CMD` step.

I could just `COPY` the file into my container, but from my reading that's supposedly not a great solution from a security standpoint.

What is the recommended, secure way of passing a secret json file to the `CMD` step of a docker container?

Comment: Your code should fetch the SA file in runtime in a secure way and never save it on disk, just in memory or secure cache and delete it after usage.

Comment: another suggestion is that if your code run on any of GCP Compute services, you can use the SA without needing keys.

Comment: thanks Atef, can you elaborate on a mechanism(s) for fetching the SA in runtime in a secure way?

Comment: When starting a container add the option **--network="host"**. The container can now access the VM instance metadata server. Your Docker application can then use ADC (Application Default Credentials) to fetch service account OAuth tokens from the metadata server.